# Python logs working on one pycharm and not on another

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

I've created this python script to help me create log files while running my script and it works perfectly in my own machine. But for some reason the exact code does not work on other machines.
In my machine it shows the logs in pycharm console and also saves them in a file. In other machines it doesn't do anything except for creating a blank file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
log = logging.getLogger('Logger Name')
try:
    logger_file_name = new_file_name()
    handler = logging.FileHandler(logger_file_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(handler)
    log.info(logger_file_name+ '  File will be used for Saving Logs')
    main()
except Exception as err:
    log.debug("An Error was found which was not caught")
    log.exception(err)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explicitly set the logging level, for example:

```
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Otherwise you're relying on the default value which *might* be different on different python versions that may be installed on different machines. For example on 2.7.12 the default level is set to `WARNING` and the `log.info()` messages won't show up - just as you observed.

From the 2.7.12 logging doc's [A simple example section](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example):

> ```
> import logging
> logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
> logging.info('I told you so')  # will not print anything
> ```
>
> If you type these lines into a script and run it, you’ll see:
>
> ```
> WARNING:root:Watch out!
> ```
>
> printed out on the console. The `INFO` message doesn’t appear because
>   the default level is `WARNING`...

Comment: I did try adding a logger.NOTSET level which can be used to print and save all the logs as I needed it but to no avail

Comment: `logger.NOTSET`'s behaviour may also be dependent on the python version - at least on 2.7.12 the `INFO` logs again won't show up with it. Try, as I mentioned, `logging.DEBUG` instead.

Comment: Using a specific level did help, however i had to truncate my logs